# Java Exceptions and Postcondition

Tags: java, class, exception, return, computer-science

**Which of the following exceptions would occur, What exception will happen?**

> // precondition: a is not null
>
> ```
> public String sampleClass(ArrayList<String> a, int b) {
>     String t;
>     int u;
>     for (u = 0; u <= a.size(); u++) {
>         t = (String)(a.get(u));
>         if (t.length() == b) {
>             return t;
>         }
>     }
>     return null;
> }
> ```

- A) NullPointerException
- B) IndexOutOfBoundsException
- C) ClassCastException

**Answer I choose :** I ran the program with a tester, and I got B. I think B would be the answer.

Comment: I would go with answer B if an only if List a does not contain a String of length b due to you iterating from 0 to a.size(), inclusive. It could also be A if List a contains null elements. It could also be answer C if you managed to add anything but Strings to List a. Answers D and E are not likely to ever occur in this method.

Answer (score 1):

Your question doesn't make sense if we don't know how doSomething is called. You could get almost of those exceptions according to the situation :

In some cases, you won't get any exceptions. For example :

```
ArrayList<String> a = new ArrayList<>();
a.add("");
doSomething(a,0);
```

The following will throw a NullPointerException :

```
ArrayList<String> a = new ArrayList<>();
a.add(null);
doSomething(a,0);
```

This one will throw an IndexOutOfBoundException :

```
doSomething(new ArrayList<>(),0)
```

Finally, you would have a ClassCastException with this one :

```
ArrayList a = new ArrayList();
a.add(new Object());
doSomething(a,0);
```

Neither D nor E are possible (D could only happen if you used an array and your code does not contain any particular arithmetic operation that could throw an exception).

Comment: You can cause a ClassCastException by casting a raw List to List< String >. This way you can add non-string Objects without completely annoying the compiler. You get lots of warnings though.

Comment: That still creates an ArrayList< String >. The <> operator infers the generics. Something like ArrayList l = new ArrayList(); l.add( 1 ); doSomething( ( ArrayList< String > ) l ), 0 );

Comment: I tested it and got the exception. It's the last snippet of my message.

Comment: That was not there when I send that comment. So that was my bad.

Comment: D should also never occur as List.get throws IndexOutOfBoundsException and no other code I believe can throw ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException that was displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a fully runnable example which shows you A, B, C and no exception occurring.

Without stating what the ArrayList contains there is no way to fully answer the question.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(final String... args) {
        try {
            Test.throwNullPointer();
        } catch (final Throwable e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

        try {
            Test.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException();
        } catch (final Throwable e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

        try {
            Test.throwClassCastException();
        } catch (final Throwable e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

        try {
            Test.noException();
            System.out.println("No Exception");
        } catch (final Throwable e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

    public static void throwNullPointer() {
        final ArrayList<String> a = new ArrayList<>();
        a.add("a");
        a.add(null);
        a.add("c");
        Test.doSomething(a, 0);
    }

    public static void throwIndexOutOfBoundsException() {
        final ArrayList<String> a = new ArrayList<>();
        a.add("a");
        a.add("b");
        a.add("c");
        Test.doSomething(a, 0);
    }

    public static void throwClassCastException() {
        final ArrayList<String> a = new ArrayList<>();
        Test.doNaughtyStuff(a);
        Test.doSomething(a, 0);
    }

    private static void doNaughtyStuff(final ArrayList a) {
        a.add(new Object());
    }

    public static void noException() {
        final ArrayList<String> a = new ArrayList<>();
        a.add("");
        Test.doSomething(a, 0);
    }

    public static String doSomething(final ArrayList<String> a, final int b) {
        String t;
        int u;
        for (u = 0; u <= a.size(); u++) {
            t = a.get(u);
            if (t.length() == b) {
                return t;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 3, Size: 3
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object cannot be cast to java.lang.String
No Exception
```